# How to change the size of box 1 according to box 2?

Tags: html, css

[image]

I am new to Web development and am doing a beginners course from freecodecamp. I am trying to do a task using media queries which is to change the layout when the resolution of the screen is made narrower or wider. Here i need to change the size of box 1 according to box 2. I have tried in my way, but box 1 is going out of box 2. I have attached the code snippet please have a look and correct me.

```css
body {
                font-family: monospace;
            }

            p {
                font-size: 14px;
                font-weight: bold;
            }

            h1 {
                text-align: center;
            }

            * {
                box-sizing: border-box;
            }

            .row {
                width: 100%;
            }

            .box1 {
                border: 1px solid black;
                width: 30%;
                padding: 10px;
                background-color: #999999;
                float: left;
                margin-right: 20px;
                margin-left: 20px;
            }

            .box2 {
                border: 1px solid black;
                width: 30%;
                padding: 10px;
                background-color: #999999;
                float: left;
                margin-right: 20px;
            }

            .row {
                margin-bottom: 15px;
                align-content: center;
                width: 100%;
            }

            .heading1 {
                text-align: center;
                padding: 2px;
                border: 1px solid black;
                margin-top: -11px;
                margin-left: 279px;
                background-color: #D59898;
                width: 30%;
                height: 30px;
                font-size: 18px;
                position: relative;
            }

            .heading2 {
                color: white;
                background-color: #C14543;
                text-align: center;
                padding: 2px;
                border: 1px solid black;
                margin-top: -11px;
                margin-left: 279px;
                width: 30%;
                height: 30px;
                font-size: 18px;
                position: relative;
            }
```

```html
<h1>Heading</h1>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 box1">
                <h5 class="heading1">Heading1</h5>
                <p>A wonderful serenity has taken possession of my entire soul, like these sweet
                    mornings of spring which I enjoy with my whole heart. I am alone, and feel the charm of existence in
                    this spot, which was created for the bliss of souls like mine. I am so happy, my dear friend, so
                    absorbed in the exquisite sense of mere tranquil existence, that I neglect my talents. I should be
                    incapable of drawing a single stroke at the present moment; and yet I feel that I never was a
                    greater</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 box2">
                <h5 class="heading2">Heading2</h5>
                <p>A wonderful serenity has taken possession of my entire soul, like these sweet
                    mornings of spring which I enjoy with my whole heart. I am alone, and feel the charm of existence in
                    this spot, which was created for the bliss of souls like mine. I am so happy, my dear friend, so
                    absorbed in the exquisite sense of mere tranquil existence, that I neglect my talents. I should be
                    incapable of drawing a single stroke at the present moment; and yet I feel that I never was a
                    greater</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: use flex-grow and flex-shrink

Comment: You can fix this by using **Flex** properties

Comment: for reference https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex-shrink/#:~:text=It%20specifies%20the%20%E2%80%9Cflex%20shrink,basis%20when%20distributing%20negative%20space.

Comment: There are no media queries in your CSS?

Comment: Thanks @KALITA, will use this reference

Comment: @Nikkorian My issue here was the alignment of box 1 when i reduce the resolution of the screen. so i just added the code of those 2 boxes. media queries were working fine.

Comment: @sreeramp96, but it's the code contained under the media queries that will determine what happens under different resolutions - perhaps I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make it `position:absolute` and place it on the top right

```css
body {
  font-family: monospace;
}

p {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
}

.box1 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 30%;
  padding:30px 10px 10px;
  background-color: #999999;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.box2 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 30%;
  padding:30px 10px 10px;
  background-color: #999999;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.row {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  align-content: center;
}

.heading1 {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  background-color: #D59898;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin:0;
}

.heading2 {
  color: white;
  background-color: #C14543;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<h1>Heading</h1>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 box1">
      <h5 class="heading1">Heading1</h5>
      <p>A wonderful serenity has taken possession of my entire soul, like these sweet mornings of spring which I enjoy with my whole heart. I am alone, and feel the charm of existence in this spot, which was created for the bliss of souls like mine. I am
        so happy, my dear friend, so absorbed in the exquisite sense of mere tranquil existence, that I neglect my talents. I should be incapable of drawing a single stroke at the present moment; and yet I feel that I never was a greater
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 box2">
      <h5 class="heading2">Heading2</h5>
      <p>A wonderful serenity has taken possession of my entire soul, like these sweet mornings of spring which I enjoy with my whole heart. I am alone, and feel the charm of existence in this spot, which was created for the bliss of souls like mine. I am
        so happy, my dear friend, so absorbed in the exquisite sense of mere tranquil existence, that I neglect my talents. I should be incapable of drawing a single stroke at the present moment; and yet I feel that I never was a greater
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```